# Nslookup suddenly won't resolve against Cloudflare

Tags: windows, cloudflare, nslookup

As of Friday afternoon Australian time, I'm getting failures using nslookup with 1.1.1.1. It works fine with 8.8.8.8, and Powershell Resolve-DnsName works fine. nslookup without specifying a server works fine, where the local DNS uses 1.1.1.1. I've tried this on a variety of Windows flavours, with a variety of ISPs and router devices.

For example:

```
powershell (resolve-dnsname www.microsoft.com -server 1.1.1.1).ip4address
104.119.97.160
```

and

```
nslookup -type=A www.microsoft.com. 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    e13678.dscb.akamaiedge.net
Address:  23.202.161.73
Aliases:  www.microsoft.com
          www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net
          www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net
```

and

```
nslookup -type=A www.microsoft.com.
Server:  fritz.box
Address:  192.168.4.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    e13678.dscb.akamaiedge.net
Address:  104.119.97.160
Aliases:  www.microsoft.com
          www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net
          www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net
```

but:

```
nslookup -type=A www.microsoft.com. 1.1.1.1
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to one.one.one.one timed-out
```

I'm wondering if Windows' nslookup does something a bit wacky and it's now failing against Cloudflare if they have done something a bit different lately?

Comment: **I'm wondering if Windows' nslookup does something a bit wacky** - Like what? It seems to work normally for me. Have you tried it from a different network? Is it possible your queries to 1.1.1.1 are being blocked by your firewall?

Comment: I did say "I've tried this on a variety of Windows flavours, with a variety of ISPs and router devices" and that it was working via PowerShell. Anyway, as of about midnight Friday, it's back to normal. So whatever was happening lasted about 7 hours and then went away.